# Мигание всплывающего окна на jquery

Tags: jquery, всплывающее-окно

Я большой новичок в этом деле, поэтому подскажите, почему в данном коде мигает окно при его наведении, я не хочу наоборот этого

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>                                                                  
<head>      
<style type="text/css">
p
{
border:1px solid;
}
</style>                                                          
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("p").mouseover(function(){ $("p").fadeTo(2000,1);});
   $("p").mouseout(function(){ $("p").fadeTo(2000,0.3);});

});                                           
</script>
                                                          
</head>
<body> 
<p>Наведите на меня курсор мыши и я изменю цвет. Когда Вы выведите курсор мыши за мои пределы я изменю цвет на стандартный.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Чтобы происходило наоборот, поменяйте `mouseover` и `mouseout`. Если я правильно Вас понял. `$(document).ready(function(){
            $("p").mouseout(function(){ $("p").fadeTo(2000,0.3);});
            $("p").mouseover(function(){ $("p").fadeTo(2000,1);});
        });`

Comment: это так не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну код не учитывает, что границу элемента можно пересекать по несколько раз, и до завершения предыдущей анимации. Вот он и выполняет всё, что многократно запустилось. Надо научиться как-то останавливать предыдущую анимацию. А в jQuery есть для этого готовая функция [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").mouseover(function(){
    // this ссылается на объект, в контексте которого вызвана функция.
    // в данном случае - <p>. Это чтобы заново по странице его не искать.
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(2000, 1);
  });
  
  $("p").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(2000, 0.3);
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  border:1px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Наведите на меня курсор мыши и я изменю цвет. Когда Вы выведите курсор мыши за мои пределы я изменю цвет на стандартный.</p>
```

Comment: странно, то мелькает, то не хочет мелькать

Comment: спасибо, помогло. Можете подсказать книгу или сайт, где можно подучить jquery?

Comment: @МаксимЛарченко Ну можно взять и пройти по списку всего, что есть → https://api.jquery.com/ но это всего лишь полезная библиотека. Невозможно что-то нормально написать на jQuery, не зная JS. Поэтому по хорошему надо выучить JS, потом уже пользоваться jQ (а может к тому времени уже и не захочется). А по JS... 1. https://learn.javascript.ru/ 2. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/ любой из них, вкусовщина.